# How int x= 1+ +2+ +3+ +4+ +5; return 15 in JAVA

Tags: java

I was asked in interview what will happen if below statement is compiled in java.

```
int x= 1+ +2+ +3+ +4+ +5;
```

It returns 15.
Can anyone explain how this goes?

Comment: *Next question:* Why does that work, but removing the spaces makes it fail to compile? `int x= 1++2++3++4++5;`

Comment: Fwiw, this kind of trivia has nothing to do with real programming, in my experience. If they're using this question in their hiring, they may not know what they're doing, and this may not be a great company to work for.

Answer (score 5):

`+` and `-` can both also be unary operators, so `1 + +5` is the same as `1 + 5`.
So expression would be translated into

```
int x = 1 + (+2) + (+3) + (+4) + (+5)
```

Comment: @MS90 As opposed to non-empty spaces? *(what is a non-empty space anyway?)*

Comment: @Andreas Is it same?

Comment: @MS90 So by "empty spaces", you simply meant "spaces"? Just asking for clarification of why you qualified "spaces" with the word "empty", as-is there are non-empty spaces you don't need to pay attention to.